# How to set default web page size in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, zoom

I recently downloaded Firefox the new version, and for most of the part it is good. Though a problem in it I found is that every time I open a new web page I need to set the zoom level to 170% so that the page becomes readable and fits the screen size. How can I set it once and for all?

Note: I am using a Windows 10 machine.

Comment: [How do I change the default magnification?](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1125554)

Comment: For all the people who are still searching for a solution, this Firefox addon has solved the issue for me: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/zoom-page-we/ There is an option in the addon settings for a default page zoom which you can set to any value you prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that many people still visit this post looking for a solution, so for here it is. You can install the Firefox add-on [Zoom Page WE](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/zoom-page-we/), then in the add-on preferences page go to `Zoom Levels & Font Size` tab and set the `Default Full Level` to whatever is best for you. On a 15'' FHD screen I found 150% works best for me.

Comment: That extension is extremely clumsy and resource-consuming.

Comment: It works very well on my laptop that has only 4 GBs of RAM.

Comment: "Works on my laptop" is anecdotal evidence. It represents only one usage scenario and 4GB of RAM means you won't be even able to open a considerable amount of tabs.

Answer (score 5):

You can set layout.css.devPixelsPerPx to 1.0 (default is -1) on the about:config page. Adjust its value in 0.1 or 0.05 steps (1.1 or 0.9) until icons or text looks right. Modifying layout.css.devPixelsPerPx affects user interface and web pages (global zoom). You can use an extension to correct the appearance of web pages.

You can open the about:config page via the location/address bar. You can accept the warning and click "I'll be careful" to continue.

http://kb.mozillazine.org/about:config

Answer (score 4):

This is one of those things that I've found perpetually frustrating with Firefox. I was using NoSquint for a while, but I found it to be a somewhat inconsistent and gnarly plugin to use. And now it's no longer being maintained and doesn't work with the most recent versions of Firefox.

Until the team at Mozilla do the sensible thing and reinstate this basic accessibility feature, I think the best extension-free solution can be found [in a comment on this bug ticket](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=332275#c52). In case that link ever breaks, I'm reposting the contents below:

> 1. Open Browser Console
>      (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console#Opening_the_Browser_Console)
> 2. On the command line (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console#Browser_Console_command_line):
>
>    To Set Global Zoom (put whatever you want instead of 1.33) enter:
>      `FullZoom._cps2.setGlobal(FullZoom.name,1.33,gBrowser.selectedBrowser.loadContext);`
>
>    To Reset (back to 1) enter:
>      `FullZoom._cps2.removeGlobal(FullZoom.name,gBrowser.selectedBrowser.loadContext);`

To be clear, the number here represents a decimalised version of zoom percentage. So as with the original question, a zoom level of 170% would be expressed as `1.7`.

Comment: My God. (and I'm an atheist). A 13-year-old thread reaching a hundred comments about something so fundamental. I wonder if they ever thought about using a fraction of the time they spent discussing this to actually go ahead and *implement* it. In the words if Linus Torvalds: [Talk is cheap. Show me the code.](https://lkml.org/lkml/2000/8/25/132)

Comment: /\ And I do realize this applies to my little rant just as well.

Answer (score 3):

May be a little bit late, but...
I was looking to solve the same problem today and this is how I got here.
For whoever this may be useful, I found in `about:config` the setting `zoom.minPercent` (Firefox 62). This sets the default zoom to all pages to the given value. It is hackish because you cannot zoom-out more (less) than this value, but I could not find anything better.
Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually found an addon called Zoom Page WE: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/zoom-page-we/ and it solved the problem. It can set a default zoom level, and then zoom in and out for any specific pages.

Comment: Does not work here (Firefox 81 Linux). With `zoom.minPercent` set at 120, after restarting Firefox the pages are shown at 100% anyway. It seems to be taken into account only when manually touching the zoom.

Answer (score 0):

This will soon be available under `Preferences -> Language and Appearance` see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1590485#c28