# Firefox and UI font size increase issue

Tags: firefox, fonts, arch-linux

I have tried to increase the font size of Firefox UI by setting the `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx` option to >1. It works as expected until I close the browser and reopen it again. Whilst the elements themselves seems to retain their previous increased size the font shrinks. It can be clearly seen in the screenshots below how in the reopened window font inside tabs is smaller.

**Firefox when option is just set:**

[image: after just setting layout.css.devPixelsPerPx>1]

---

**Firefox after reopening:**
[image: after reopening]

Is it possible to make the font size increase permanent?

I am using Arch Linux and Firefox 89.0.

Thanks :)

Comment: If I use the Zoom function in Firefox 89 in Ubuntu and change from 100 to 133, it takes effect. If I close FF and re-open, the same (133) zoom level is present. Did you try the zoom function?

Comment: @John Zoom works for content, but it doesn't change the font size of the UI itself.

Comment: Try the extension [Theme Font & Size Changer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/theme-font-size-changer/) to set the global zoom.

Comment: @harrymc I have tried it, but it only allows changing font color these days: "Because of the new extension system on Firefox, most of the functionality of the Theme Font & Size Changer is not available any more."

Comment: It's not normal for an `about:config` setting not to stay. Try setting it again after disabling all extensions in `about:addons`.

Comment: @harrymc in a way it does stay, the setting itself is still there, also content remains scaled even after re-opening the browser, the only thing that gets reset is the font size of UI. I am starting to think this is a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `about:config` setting of `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx` persists,
but has no effect after restart, this is most likely a bug in Firefox.

Before signalling the bug, try disabling all extensions in `about:addons`,
to see if this is caused by bad extension. See also
[How to Uninstall or Disable Extensions in Mozilla Firefox](https://www.howtogeek.com/702093/how-to-uninstall-or-disable-extensions-in-mozilla-firefox/).

Otherwise, while waiting for the Firefox developers to fix the bug,
you could try using `userChrome.css`.
To enable `userChrome.css` and `userContent.css`, you need to set in `about:config` the following:
`toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets = true`.
See also
[How to Create a userChrome.css File](https://www.userchrome.org/how-create-userchrome-css.html).

Try adding this to the file, adapting it to your needs :

```
/* global font */
* {
  font-family: DejaVu, sans-serif !important;
  font-size: 13pt !important;
}
```

More information in the article
[Firefox/Tweaks](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Firefox/Tweaks).

You could also try the more extensive global UI fix from Github:
[Firefox-UI-Fix](https://github.com/black7375/Firefox-UI-Fix).

Comment: the userChrome.css works!

Comment: @harrymc sorry for the late reply, I have tried the userChrome.css solution, and the problem is that it does not load up after Firefox restart. For some reason the file does not show up in the Browser Toolbox -> Style Editor window.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to run some javascript in the console after closing Firefox until the bug is fixed

> 1. Open Browser Console (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console#Opening_the_Browser_Console)
> 2. On the command line (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console#Browser_Console_command_line):
>
> To Set Global Zoom (put whatever you want instead of 1.33) enter:
> `FullZoom._cps2.setGlobal(FullZoom.name,1.33,gBrowser.selectedBrowser.loadContext);`
> To Reset (back to 1) enter:
> `FullZoom._cps2.removeGlobal(FullZoom.name,gBrowser.selectedBrowser.loadContext);`

[source](https://superuser.com/a/1368974/130693)